# How can I replace jQuery Tools Scrollable bullets with numbers?

Tags: jquery, carousel

I'm using jQuery Tools for creating an article carousel.
You can see in action with images here: http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/scrollable/plugins/index.html

The navigation code looks like this:

```
<!-- wrapper for navigator elements -->
<div class="navi"></div>
```

And the plugin ads links like so:

```
<!-- wrapper -->
<div class="navi">
    <a href="0" class="active"/>
    <a href="1" class=""/>
    <a href="2" class=""/>
</div>
```

The code to get it all started goes like this:

```
$(".scrollable").scrollable({ circular: true, size: 1}).navigator();
```

My question is:
How can I replace  `<a href="1" class=""/>` with `<a href="1" class=""> [1] </a>` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the second demo page.

http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/scrollable/one-sized.html

Comment: humm... yeah. It looks like the only option.